# ListView displayed on the same line QML

Tags: listview, header, delegates, qml

I tried to wrap a ListView in a Rectangle and it succeed but now I have a problem. The header and delegate rows are display on the same line like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRoyF.jpg

I want it to be like this but it's not scrollable : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDkt9.jpg

This is my code :

```
    Rectangle {
       id:listViewRec
       visible: true
       anchors.fill: parent
       anchors.topMargin: 100 * wdw.height / 1080
       anchors.bottomMargin: 30 * wdw.height / 1080
       anchors.leftMargin: 30 * wdw.width / 1920
       anchors.rightMargin: 30 * wdw.width / 1920
       ListView {
       id: listViewDispInf
       anchors.fill: parent
       width: listViewRec.width
       height: listViewRec.height
       clip: true
       orientation: ListView.Horizontal
       flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick
       boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
       model: batteries
       header: Row {
          function itemAt(index) { return repeater1.itemAt((index)) }
          Repeater {
             id: repeater1
             model: Parameters { }
             Rectangle {
                height: 50 * wdw.height / 1080
                width: 1.1 * txt1.paintedWidth
                Text {
                   id: txt1
                   anchors.centerIn: parent
                   text: name
                }
             }
          }
      }
      delegate : Row {
         id: delegate
         property var informations: model.modelData
         function itemAt(index) { return repeater2.itemAt((index)) }
         Repeater {
            id: repeater2
            model: 26
            Rectangle {
                height: (listViewRec.height - listViewDispInf.headerItem.itemAt(index).height ) / 6
                width: listViewDispInf.headerItem.itemAt(index).width
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: delegate.informations.getInformations(index)
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The model come from my main.cpp like this :

```
QList<QObject *> dataList;
dataList.append(b1);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("batteries", QVariant::fromValue(dataList));
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a correct value for the `ListView` [`orientation`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-listview.html#orientation-prop).

You should remove the line or use `orientation: ListView.Vertical`

---

Edit: also, looking at your code it looks like you are actually looking for a [`TableView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html).

You could use different columns and the [resizeColumnsToContents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#resizeColumnsToContents-method) method instead of using Rows and calculating the width of each item.

Comment: First of all thanks you for your answer.

I tried your answer and it's the same problem my header is on the same line as the delegate. So all of my ListView is on a single line.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example is not complete and verifiable, we don't have enough information to reproduce the problem. What is your model? Your delegate?

Comment: I complete my example code, add some screen and the mode origins for a better explanation.

Comment: I still think your problem is the horizontal orientation. I tried your code using my own fake ListModel and with `orientation: ListView.Vertical` and it works fine. You specify an horizontal ListView, so it's the expected behavior to have it on the same line.

Comment: Also it looks like you are overcomplicated things. For your example, a TableView would be more appropriate in my opinion. See my edited answer.

Comment: With ListView.Vertical is your ListView horizontally scrollable ?

At first I tested with a TableView but it's not the output expected.

Comment: I am not sure, that's actually an interesting question. I don't think the ListView is meant to be used that way (vertical view but horizontal scroll) so it's maybe not possible. Even used inside a Flickarea, the ListView might steal the wheel event (not tested). I believe a TableView could do it. If you really don't want to use a TableView, maybe try using Rows in a Flickarea. I don't have a better solution in mind.

Comment: Oh yeah i will try with Rows included in a Flickable.

In fact I want my application to be read like a table with informations in the header and rows for the content and I found ListView but you say that ListView isn't appropriate for this so I will change